# How to print to directly to a wireless printer

Tags: 13.04, lubuntu

[NetworkPrintingWithUbuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkPrintingWithUbuntu#Printing_from_Ubuntu) describes how to handle "Network Printing":

> to another Ubuntu or Windows machine that has a printer attached

I just want to print directly to a wireless printer not via a print sever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer depends on the protocols supported by the Wireless printer.
Usually, the procedure is exactly the same as written in the link you posted. So, simply find out the IP address and enter it in the "Host" text field under "discover network printer". If this doesn't work, then you have to enter the URL of the print server.

Nearly all network capable printers understand either the lpd/lpr or the ipp protocol, many can handle both.

Consult the printers manual to find out the ipp or lpr URL to use and and enter it in the corresponding text field in the "new printer" dialogue. Often it's either `lpd://IP-ADDRESS/lpr` or `ipp://IP-ADDRESS/ipp`.

Comment: There is a bug in the version. "sudo start cups" fixes it. Your answer explains the local vs server issue.